# Why does restoring force of a spring vary directly with elongation or compression?

Tags: electromagnetism, springs, deformation, forces

The restoring force is **electromagnetic in origin, having to do with atomic/molecular interactions.**
 *Both electrostatic as well as magnetic forces vary inversly with the square of distance.*
 $F_{_{EM}}\propto \cfrac{1}{d^2}$

**So why does the restoring force vary directly with the length of the spring?**
$F_{s}\propto x \implies F_{s}=-kx$

PS
In [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/785219/origination-of-internal-forces-in-a-beam-under-axial-loads) it has been said that applying force  on the object does try to displace atoms away from each other so electromagnetic forces should reduce.

Comment: Welcome Nietsniewton to Engineering Stack Exchange. You may want to look at [Hooke's law and atomic scale](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/602283/145491), [How is potential energy actually stored in a steel spring at the atomic level?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/146871/145491) , [Why do materials obey Hooke's law?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/418906/145491), and [Can Hooke's law be derived?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/408987/145491) over on Physics Stack Exchange.

Comment: The inverse square relationship only applies to a point charge. It doesn't even apply for the force exerted by 2 charged objects, let alone $10^{23}$

Comment: You can design springs where the restoring force is not linear to elongation.

Answer (score 0):

The Hooks law applies to elastic material or springs. Their electrostatic configuration doesn't change during loading and unloading.

They have their fibers unwinding or crystals straining or other linear strain-stress relations.

Interaction at the molecular/electron level in the sense you referring produces resistance at orders of magnitude higher. those are the forces that keep us on the surface of the earth on our feet, or in a hard car collision don't let the opposing car's molecules get penetrated by the other car. (they just smash each other).

An example of an exception to elastic behavior could be an artillery explosion: the impact converts a huge amount of kinetic energy to heat so it can melt and burn and chemically change the armor and render it weak.

Answer (score 0):

Hooke's law is an *approximation good for small values of spring deflection*. Here is why it's a good approximation:

In a chunk of material being pulled in a tensile test, the pull force is very tiny compared to the sheer number of atoms in the test sample. This means that the atoms in the solid are deflected by the external stress from their equilibrium positions in the lattice by a very very very tiny amount.

A simplified linear deflection model works very well in this case, even though the electrostatic force is not linear with distance.

Answer (score 0):

It does need to. The springs you are referring to are designed specifically to have the restoring force linearly vary with elongation. It doesn't need to.